# JOIN two (2) Datasets from different DB on BIRT Designer (v.4.4.0)

Tags: sql, oracle, dataset, birt

I would like to ask about my problem that i faced these days during "designing" some reports with BIRT Designer (v.4.4.0). 
I tried making an UNION DATASET but that didnt work for me. I can make a SWITCH formula for Name and Surname from the workers but i have to write over 500 Names and Surnames with ID on the formel. So that technique doesnt work.

The Example is like this below. I have two databases and of course tables on it.

```
Database Name:   DB_1
Table Name:      Production

    Worker_ID     Machine_ID     Project     Good     Bad
    1188          001            Test_01      5        0
    1005          001            Test_01      6        0
```

and

```
Database Name:   DB_2
Table Name:      User

    Worker_ID     Name      Surname
    1188          John       Doe
    1005         Donald     Trump
```

I would like to show on table that info like this on BIRT Designer

```
Machine_ID    Project    Good    Bad    Worker_ID    Worker_Name    Worker_surname
001           Test_01     5       0        1188          John            Doe
001           Test_01     6       0        1005         Donald          Trump
```

Can anyone help me with SQL or with some tutorials about this problem?

If someone will help me with some Screenshots i would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to have a `database link` on `DB_1` or `DB_2`.

Assuming you have such a `$ORACLE_HOME/network/admin/tnsnames.ora` file for DB_2 :

```
DB_2 =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = mydb2)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = bp83.mycompany.com)
    )
  )
```

Let's create a db-link on `DB_1` targeting to `DB_2` :

```
create public database link DB2_LNK
  connect to HR -- assumed schema name
  using 'mydb2:1521/bp83.mycompany.com';
```

and need an inner join query now (assuming you're on `DB_1` then):

```
select p.machine_id as "Machine_ID", p.project as "Project", p.good as "Good", p.bad as "Bad", u.Worker_ID as "Worker_ID", u.Name as "Worker_Name", u.Surname as "Worker_surname" -- with formatted titles
  from Production p inner join hr.User_@DB2_LNK u  -- a keyword "user" cannot be used as a table name("ORA-00903: invalid table name" error raises when you attempt), so i assumed table name as "User_".
    on ( u.Worker_ID = p.Worker_ID )
```

Comment: Hi there, i was trying that and this error showed. 
https://ibb.co/myKCg6

something is missing and i dont have any idea right now ...